# How can I get auto-indentation to work with Python 2.7 on Xcode 7.3?

Tags: python, xcode, python-2.7

I've used [this guide](https://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/building-and-running-python-scripts-with-xcode-6-1/) to set up Xcode to build Python scripts. When I press return, the cursor always goes back to the beginning of the new line, even though automatic indenting based on syntax is turned on in the preferences menu. It's frustrating to have to press the space key eight times to get two blocks in indenting in every time. Is there something I haven't installed correctly? I have Anaconda installed and as my build tool if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest running Python on something else imho. Something like PyCharm or IPython. The problem with Xcode is that Python is not one of the native languages for it. So Xcode doesn't know the proper formatting for Pythons syntax. 
Not to mention that debugging and other features might not work well on Xcode.

Comment: Trying PyCharm right now. I'm just coding for an introductory class but I've done C++ on Xcode in the past. Not exactly an expert and didn't know that Xcode wasn't supposed to run Python so thank you for the help!